# C# Console isn't adding the values correctly and i'm not sure why :/

Tags: c#

This Console Application is Supposed to Display Prices and then set it in a average format and in a Less than NUM and Higher then NUM which I am entirely confused. The total and the Average come Out to the right amount just not the lessthanfive and the higherthanaverage.

CODE:

```
            double[] prices = new double[5];
        int count = 0;
        double TotalValues = 0;
        double Average = 0;
        string inputString;
        double lessthanfive = 0;
        double higherthanaverage = 0;
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < prices.Length; x++)
        {
            count += 1;
            Console.Write("Enter the price for {0}: ", count);
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            prices[x] = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
            TotalValues += prices[x];
            Average = TotalValues / prices.Length;
            if (prices[x] < 5)
                lessthanfive++;

            if (prices[x] > Average)
                higherthanaverage++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Sum of The Values Are: {0}", TotalValues.ToString("C2"));
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers Less Than $5.00 Are: {0}", lessthanfive.ToString("C2"));
        Console.WriteLine("The Average of The 20 Prices Are: {0}", Average.ToString("C2"));
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers Higher then Average Are: {0}", higherthanaverage.ToString("C2"));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem? Did you debug your code and see your what is your variables exactly?

Comment: When I run it the total and average are calculated correctly just not the less than 5.00 and higher then average

Comment: I don't think you want to use a rolling average that changes for each price

Comment: @Zubair -- No, please update your question to make it clearer.  Don't put clarifications in in the comments.

Comment: well, `Average` changes with each iteration.  So your final result of what is less than or what is greater than `Average` has a good chance of being wrong.

Comment: Usually average is defined as sum of all divided by count of all. What you have is add next and divide by total count, then add again and again divide by 20, and then again, and again - something entirely different

Comment: In addition to the problem with your implementation of the average calculation, it is not clear whether `Numbers Less Than...` and `Numbers Higher Than...` refer to a sum of monetary value or an integer count of the number of instances.  You are using a `double` precision variable to store the information and you are formatting the output with `$` to indicate a monetary value, but you are incrementing the value with `++`, which is typically used for counting.  Ideally, actually, you should use the `Decimal` type for storing monetary values and not `double`, but that's a complete aside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your average is going to be wrong, and your counts are going to be off because of it.  Calculating everything outside of that loop will keep things easy to debug, as well.  Now, this isn't the most elegant solution out there, but it uses a List to leverage the built-in Sum and Average functions, as well as allowing your list to be re-sizable, in case you don't want to add 20 numbers each time.

```
        List<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>();
        int numPrices;
        decimal totalPrice;
        decimal averagePrice;
        string inputString;
        int lessThanFive = 0;
        int higherThanAverage = 0;

        Console.Write("Enter the number of prices that you will be entering: ");
        numPrices = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numPrices; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the price for item #{0}: $", i+1);
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            prices.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(inputString));
        }

        totalPrice = prices.Sum();
        averagePrice = prices.Average();

        foreach (decimal item in prices)
        {
            if (5 > item)
            {
                lessThanFive++;
            }
            if (averagePrice > item)
            {
                higherThanAverage++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the values are: {0:C}", totalPrice);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of prices less than $5.00 are: {0}", lessThanFive);
        Console.WriteLine("The average of the prices entered is: {0:C}", averagePrice);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of prices that are higher than average are: {0}", higherThanAverage);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, I used decimal instead of double for these because, well, in this example it certainly wouldn't need a double for anything, but it could be converted back without any problems.  Also added some minor string formatting, etc.  The main thing is, I checked the math and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know the average until after the last value has been entered, so you need another loop to count the number of items above the average:

```
for (x = 0; x < prices.Length; x++)
{
  count += 1;
  Console.Write("Enter the price for {0}: ", count);
  inputString = Console.ReadLine();
  prices[x] = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
  TotalValues += prices[x];
  if (prices[x] < 5) {
    lessthanfive++;
  }
}

Average = TotalValues / prices.Length;

for (x = 0; x < prices.Length; x++)
{
   if (prices[x] > Average) {
     higherthanaverage++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The average is calculated in the wrong scope (inside the loop) and so is the higherthanaverage. To fix it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] prices = new double[5];
        int count = 0;
        double TotalValues = 0;
        double Average = 0;
        string inputString;
        double lessthanfive = 0;
        double higherthanaverage = 0;
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < prices.Length; x++)
        {
            count += 1;
            Console.Write("Enter the price for {0}: ", count);
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            prices[x] = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);
            TotalValues += prices[x];
            if (prices[x] < 5)
                lessthanfive++;
        }

        Average = prices.Average();
        higherthanaverage = prices.Where(price => price > Average).Count();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Sum of The Values Are: {0:C2}", TotalValues);
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers Less Than $5.00 Are: {0:C2}", lessthanfive);
        Console.WriteLine("The Average of The 20 Prices Are: {0:C2}", Average);
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers Higher then Average Are: {0:C2}", higherthanaverage);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```